# R - ifelse statement with two conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm new to R and want to understand why "ifelse" fails in my case.

I have a vector of longitudes and radii. If the lons are < 0 then the code should do lons - (zrad/dxy), if lons are >= 0 then lons + (zrad/dxy) should be calculated.

Some example data:

```
lons <- c(-80,4)
zrad <- c(747,576)
dxy  <- 222
```

```
test <- ifelse(lons < 0 | lons >= 0, lons - (zrad/dxy), lons + (zrad/dxy))
View(test)
```

This gives me

```
1   -83.364865
2   1.405405
```

However, lons - (zrad/dxy) is

```
-83.364865  1.405405
```

and lons + (zrad/dxy) is

```
-76.635135  6.594595
```

But the right result should be

```
-83.364865 6.594595
```

Do I need to use a for-loop so that "test" includes the result from the first and second calculation?
Or is there an easier way to differentiate the two cases(conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is incorrect, `lons < 0 | lons >= 0` are basically all the numbers hence it executes only `lons - (zrad/dxy)`.  Try :

```
test <- ifelse(lons < 0, lons - (zrad/dxy), lons + (zrad/dxy))
test
#[1] -83.364865   6.594595
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
test <- case_when(lons < 0 ~ lons - (zrad/dxy), TRUE ~ lons + (zrad/dxy))
```